# How to overlap Bootstrap Navbar on Carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a mock up and I want a full-screen carousel with the nav bar links sitting on top of the images. Currently, the navbar is clear and when I scroll down on the image/slider it's full screen. How can I have the nav bar lay on top of the carousel on initial load? I am using BS4 alpha also.

**Currently:**
[current position of nav bar on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayMs5.png)

**Wanted:** [wanted position of navbar on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwuJe.png)

Code:

```css
html,body {
  height:100vh;
}
.carousel, .item, .active {
  height:100vh;
}
.carousel { 
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height:100vh;
}
.carousel-inner img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!--nav bar  -->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cold Denver</a>

  <!-- all the links inside mobile menu  -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <!-- left side nav bar  -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Store</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- end nav  -->

<div id="fullCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" width="100%" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" width="100%" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" width="100%" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#fullCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#fullCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try using `position:absolute` in `navbar`

Comment: @MukeshRam there is no change when I add that in the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per you html file try adding the below code.
**Explanation**
when you make Carousel position:absolute with top:0, it goes on top , overlapping all html components, now to make it full screen we use 100% width. here the navbar is not visible now it is their but not visible it is behind the carousel, so to make it visible we use z-index:9;

```
.navbar{
 z-index:9; 
}
#fullCarousel{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
}
```

i hope you understand.

Comment: That code worked for me. Would you care to elaborate as to why? Also the navbar z index code isn't needed. Also the width and position can be applied to both the id and class and still work.

Comment: you can use z-index:9 in navbar or you can also use z-index:-1 in carousel

Answer (score 0):

Try changing absolute position or Z index.

Comment: When i add the absolute positioning to the carousel with "top: 0;" the carousel goes to the top left corner.

Comment: try this: position: `absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;`

Comment: The carousel is going to the top left corner and not extending the full width when this happens. With just absolute and top 0.